# Use livewire->emit() from a common class in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I need to update a livewire datatable using `->emit('refreshDataTable');` from a Laravel job or service, since it is asynchronous, I cannot do it from the component, since when it is updated, the Job is still running

it's possible?

Comment: take a look at this https://freek.dev/1894-display-real-time-progress-of-batched-jobs-using-livewire

Comment: and also this https://philo.dev/laravel-batches-and-real-time-progress-with-livewire/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to refresh the component after the queue job is finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64186425/how-to-refresh-the-component-after-the-queue-job-is-finished)